# useWindowDimensions is not modified when keyboard is on screen

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to calculate the height of the screen when the keyboard appears (testing on an Android device). Tried with useWindowDimensions but width/height doesn't change. I've created a small example [here](https://snack.expo.dev/kG7FoV3W_).

```
export default function App() {
  const [something, setSomething] = useState("")
  
  const window = useWindowDimensions();
  

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Here I'm expecting width or height to change if I focus 
                on the input because keyboard will be shown</Text>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        width: {window.width} - height: {window.height}
      </Text>
      <TextInput
          style={[styles.textInput]}
          autoCompleteType="email"
          placeholder="something"
          value={something}
          onChangeText={(text) => setSomething(text)}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
        />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if re-defining the `useDimensions` would work.

Anyway, you could use the [Keyboard Hooks](https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks#usekeyboard) from react-native-community to get the height of the keyboard and then subtract to the initial height.

It probably works well with a KeyboardListener as well

Answer (score 0):

Check the AndroidManifest.xml

look at :
<activity

android:name=".MainActivity"

android:label="@string/app_name"

and look for this
=> android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"

if this line is missed
Add it.