# React native KeyboardAvoidingView only adjusts height once on android

Tags: android, react-native

I am using the following react native version:

```
 "react-native": "^0.64.0",
```

I have the following code:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.setupContainer} behavior={this.state.edit ? "": "height"}>
 <View>
  ...
 </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

It works as expected on iOS - It adjusts the height of the inner view, if edit is false and the keyboard is shown.
But on Android it is doing that only one time. After that one time the adjustment is not done again. If I restart the app and try it again it works again for one time and the not anymore.

In my AndroidManifest.xml file I have the following line:

```
 <activity 
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
 >
```

I am not sure where the mistake is. Logging `this.state.edit` gives `false` all the time, so this can not be the guilty one.

Thanks for any help.

My stylings:

```
  setupContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    zIndex: 2,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: blackStyle
  },
```

Comment: See if this helps you for now https://stackoverflow.com/a/68562755/16366874.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Also adding a listener does not help. It is not triggered even though the keyboard is shown: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51606247/9408779